# font awesome library with npm

Tags: npm, node-modules, font-awesome, github-pages

now i want to understand, i am working on project and i am using font awesome library and i installed it with npm, so the library works fine in my machine but when i hosting the website in github pages the icons don't work and it tells me this in the console:
GET https://billalben.github.io/html-css-template-two/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
, of course i ignored the node_modules folder, so now can anybody tells me what should i do, should i not ignore node_moludes or what, or something i don't understand it, please enlighten me. Thank you.

now i want to use font awesome library with npm and i want to work fine without any problem